# Facebook.php causes error in apache log, how to fix?

Tags: facebook, apache, curl, logging

I have a Facebook application running on Amazon servers (windows data center + apache) and this shows up in the apache error log a lot:

"Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information"

In facebook.php the error is generated here:

```
 if ((curl_errno($ch) == 60) || (curl_errno($ch) == 77)) { // CURLE_SSL_CACERT || CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE
  self::errorLog('Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
      dirname(__FILE__) . '/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

I have the latest fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt from github in the same directory.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/issue/7).

Comment: yep, the certificate is now included in the SDK: fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you solved it?

Comment: I have downloaded the SDK again and replaced facebook.php and fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt. That solved the problem, but I still don't know where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download facebook.php and the fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt certificate again and replace them with your current files.

Comment: Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/facebook-php-sdk/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt';